# Order Book vs Wallet Updates

Tags: limit-order-book

Good morning,

i am in the middle of developing my own stock exchange system and have implemented limit orders (basics) matching. The system is just a DIY solution for my own purposes and for fun mainly. The whole system is utilising my own text protocol for traders to be able to login/place orders/receive notifications. This is done for BTC exchange.

However i am stuck when it comes to calculations of the traders wallets.

I don't think i know exactly what is going on behind the scenes therefore i would really appreciate if somebody could shed a bit of light on it for me.

I believe wallets are updated only in 3 places:

- New Order is placed: What happens with trader wallet when he places order (buy/sell)
- Cancel order is placed: What happens with trader wallet when he places cancel order (buy/sell)
- Match is made and a Trade is generated (full/partial) - what happens with te wallets of both traders?

What i am trying to understand is what happens with the BTC's and USD's in Traders wallets when orders are placed/cancelled/matched and how is this handled.

Thank you very much for your input into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the transactions affect the account. See example implementation below. The `position` and `money` should be initialized at the beginning. Note that both of them, and also `quantity` can be positive and negative.

```
public static class PNL {
    private double position = 0; // number of BTC
    private double money = 0.0; // USD

    public double get_position() {
        return position;
    }

    public void on_execution(double price, double quantity) {
        position += quantity;
        money -= quantity * price;
    }

    public double get_pnl(double current_price){
        return money + position * current_price;
    }
}
```

When a new order is placed or an existing order modified, it affects the risk and exposure of the account. The risk manager must validate that in worst-case-scenario the the exposure will not breach the exposure limitations. Also, it needs to take into account the In-Flight state of orders. Here is an an [example](http://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/iLink+Order+Cancel-Replace+and+In-Flight+Mitigation) how CME allows to manage it.
Similarly, order cancellation also affects only the risk management.

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear explanation.

Therefore when i place an order, say Buy 2@100, before it is put to the orderbook a 'Risk manager' checks if i have enough money (200 here) to place this order? 

Because if not, i would be able to place 100 of these orders to the orderbook even if have not enough money to cover it.